# Whenever I move files to the desktop, they get encrypted

Tags: windows-7, encryption

So when I create a file in a folder, say a *.docx, and I move said file to the desktop and then back to the folder, it appears with green letters (encrypted). Same happens for every file I create on the Desktop.
Basically every file that touches or goes through the Desktop gets encrypted automatically.... why!?

Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 4):

Go to Run and enter the following:

**%userprofile%**

Locate the folder Desktop and right click --> **Properties**

In the **General** Tab , click on **Advanced** and make sure the Encrypt contents to secure data is not checked

[image]

Check also:

[Windows 7 Encryption](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/encrypt-decrypt-folder-file#1TC=windows-7)